# Java JEditorPane

Tags: java, jeditorpane

[ChatGUI](http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/1961/chatrp.jpg)

im using 2 JEditorPane to transfer text from one to another.

once i have transfered the data i do the following:

```
JEditorPane.setText(null);

JEditorPane.setCaretPosition(0);
```

but as you can see from the attached image the return action makes the prompt appear a row down. how can i fix this?

EDIT: does the following seem correct to you? if so then why is caret not positioning itself to chracter 0 position?

```
    private class MyKeyAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {

        int kc = ke.getKeyCode();

        if (kc == ke.VK_ENTER) {

            System.out.println(editorPaneHistory.getText());

            System.out.println(editorPaneHomeText.getText());

            editorPaneHistory.setText(editorPaneHomeText.getText());

            //JEditorPane - editorPaneHistory
            //JEditorPane - editorPaneHomeText

            editorPaneHomeText.setText(null);

            editorPaneHomeText.setCaretPosition(0);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, but my caret disappears after I "clean it" and when I click on the the JEditorPane that I created, the caret reapears in the top. Maybe there is something wrong elsewhere

Comment: you could share your example please?

Comment: what do you mean by "clean it"? are you doing something that i am not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your code runs, the JEditorPane is reacting to the enter key in the usual way, by inserting a newline.  Try calling `ke.consume()` to "consume" the event so that the JEditorPane itself doesn't handle it.

Comment: could provide a small example? in my attempts when i put ke.consume(); the "enter" stops responding.

Comment: forgot to mention. once i positioned .consume() correctly it, it performs flawlessly! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a KeyListener. You should be using a custom Action. This way you can replace the default Action. Read up on [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/).